# Is there a file explorer/manager for the command line?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, files, filemanager, ncurses

I would like to know if there is something like DOS interface for Ubuntu. I mean a "GUI" that can run from the console (for example if you are using Ubuntu Server). Some file explorer like Nautilus but in console.

[image]

Comment: Is [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DOSBox) what your looking for maybe?

Comment: No, i don't want to run DOS programs, I want a GUI for file exploring, searching WiFi networks, something like Nautilus but in a console

Comment: For file searching you have `midnight commander`, for scanning wifi networks I do not know, for web browsing you have `w3m`, for playing music you can use `sox`.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Byobu

Comment: Nice !!! Byobu with MidnigthCommander is exactly what I need ;)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Well there is **midnight commander**:

[image: mcscreenshot]
To install: `sudo apt-get install mc`
To run: `mc`

And also **Last File Manager**:

[image: lfmscreenshot]
To install: `sudo apt-get install lfm`
To run: `lfm`

Comment: Does they support full control by keyboard? Because I can't use mouse on Ubuntu Server

Comment: Midnight commander does work entirely from the keyboard.  If function keys aren't available, you can use ESC followed by the digit corresponding to the function key.

Comment: Why anyone would choose *Last File Manager* over midnight commander?

Comment: Similar to @BillThor comment: **M-<chr>:** Press Alt key and a character key at the same time. Useful if you are inside [Byobu](http://byobu.co/).

Answer (score 27):

**[Ranger:](http://nongnu.org/ranger/)**

> ranger is a file manager with **VI key bindings**. It provides a
>   minimalistic and nice curses interface with a view on the directory
>   hierarchy. The secondary task of ranger is to psychically guess which
>   program you want to use for opening particular files.

- UTF-8 Support
- Multi-column display
- Preview of the selected file/directory
- Common file operations (create/chmod/copy/delete/...)
- VIM-like console and hotkeys
- Automatically determine file types and run them with correct programs
- Change the directory of your shell after exiting ranger
- Tabs, Bookmarks, Mouse support

[image]

[image]

Comment: What a fantastic program. I owe you a beer for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: On Mac, `brew install ranger` and bam!

Answer (score 26):

Another useful filemanager that can be operated entirely from the keyboard is `vifm` and it is available in the repositories. You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install vifm
```

It has an ncurses style interface and is ideal for using on servers. It is quite similar to the other dual pane file managers mentioned except that it supports all the `vim` shortcuts. If you know all the various ways of operating in `vim`, then this file manager will be ideal and you will not need to learn another slew of shortcuts.

A `vifmrc` is created in a `~/.vifm` folder when the program is installed, so you can add your own personal configurations and keybindings. However, to fully use all the more recent features such as customising keybindings you will need to compile the latest version from [the project site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vifm/files/vifm/), and make sure you install the minimum build dependencies `libmagic-dev` and `libx11-dev`. The version in the repositories is fine and stable, but it is quite an old version (0.4.2) and the current version is 0.7.4.

Just like in `vim`, you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> to enter the command line inside the file browser and perform many actions, as as noted in the documentation at [the Sourceforge site](http://vifm.sourceforge.net/docs.html). The creator of the program indeed uses it for his home server, as he shows in his [screenshots](http://vifm.sourceforge.net/pictures.html) here, so I think the program would be perfect for you, or anyone already familar with `vim`.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You could take a look at [Dired Mode for Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dired). Though it's integrated to Emacs (so you have to learn the whole stuff), it's so much useful and nice to use that it could be nice to try it.

You can display a repository in in the console by running it in `no-window` mode:

```
emacs -nw /path/to/your/repository/
```

> Dired is a visual directory editor, a computer program for editing file system directories. Dired runs on any Emacs platform. Its commands are generally more modal than most Emacs commands because Dired is a specialized major mode on its own. Dired can perform all expected operations; in operation and use it is akin to an orthodox file manager like Midnight Commander.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This thread reminded me that you can open a directory with `vim` and browse it from there with arrow keys and enter. Which is about all I wanted. :+1:

```
vim .
```

Comment: long term I want one of the other file managers mentioned, but this deserves +2 because it's available by default in more locations.

Answer (score 0):

I like the netrw script for VI:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1075